# How to delete a file in HDFS which is in different cluster?

Tags: hdfs

I am creating a workflow in which I need to delete some HDFS files which are in a different cluster. Below is the command that i have tried

```
clusterA-ip ] $ hdfs dfs -rm hdfs://clusterB-ip:8888/path/to/the/file.txt
```

But this is not working. Could you please help?

Comment: What error does it print? If versions of local and remote clusters are compatible AND you have network connectivity to remote cluster AND you have proper access rights on remote cluster, then above command should work.

Comment: The issue was with the namenode port. I should use 8020 instead of 8888. This has resolved my issue.